# What is more resourse-efficient?

Tags: c#

Consider this code I found in Daniel Shullers book on C# game programming:

```
Monster
{
string _name;
int _currentLevel = 1;
int _currentExperience = 0;
int _nextLevelExperience = 1000;

public void LevelUp()
{
Console.WriteLine(_name + "has levelled up!");
_currentLevel++;
_currentExperience = 0;
_nextLevelExperience = _currentLevel * 1000;
}
}
```

The question is:
Is making a `_nextLevelExperience` field to be calculated this way is more efficient than, say making a data file which holds predefined all `_nextLevelExperience` values respective to `_currentLevel` and make program access and read the data.

Is some small computation worth it?

Comment: how could you compile this code with `¼`  ??

Comment: this is my first post, please don't be to harsh at me :) 
I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calculation takes up 0 memory and has a negligible computation time. If the calculation is really that simple, then leave it as a calculation.

Don't worry about performance until performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could very well try it yourself...but you'll surely find that I/O operations are going to be slower than the calculation, and that's without considering multiple instances trying to access the same file and other such concerns.